Sqlite3 getting outdated value when selecting straight after inserting
I'm having a very wiered behavior with sqlite3 in python.
I have a small flask service which has 2 endpoints addTask and deleteTask, and in my database I have tasks_order column which holds array that represents the tasks ordering. this order is changeable by the user.
addTask - pushes a new random id (task id) into tasks_order array and to the database, this is its code:
Endpoint:
@tasks_bp.route("/addTask", methods=["POST"])
def addTask():
    hash = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation) for _ in range(10))
    data = request.get_json()
    return tasksService.addTask(hash)

Service:
def addTask(hash):
    try:
        conn = db.getConn()
        new_task_id = random.randint(1, 999)
        tasks_order = dbm.getTasksOrderList()
        dbm.updateTasksOrderList(tasks_order + [new_task_id])
        conn.commit()
        tasks_order = dbm.getTasksOrderList()
        print(hash, "added", new_task_id, datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S.%f"))
        print(hash, tasks_order, datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S.%f"))
    except Exception as e:
        conn.rollback()
        raise e
    else:
        return {"id": new_task_id}

dbm:
def getTasksOrderList():
    cur = db.getConn().cursor()
    row = cur.execute("SELECT order_list FROM tasks_order").fetchone()
    order_list_str = row["order_list"]
    return json.loads(order_list_str)


def updateTasksOrderList(order_list):
    order_list_str = json.dumps(order_list)
    cur = db.getConn().cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE tasks_order SET order_list = ?", (order_list_str,))

Notice that I'm addid hash and some prints for debugging manners only.
deleteTask - receives a task id, selects the tasks_order array from the database, removes this task id then updates the tasks_order in database. Here's its code:
Endpoint:
@tasks_bp.route("/deleteTask", methods=["POST"])
def deleteTask():
    try:
        hash = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation) for _ in range(10))
        data = request.get_json()
        return tasksService.deleteTask(hash, data["task_id"])
    except Exception as e:
        print(hash, "ERROR OCCURED", data["task_id"])

Service:
def deleteTask(hash, task_id):
    print(hash, "todelete", task_id, datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S.%f"))
    try:
        conn = db.getConn()
        tasks_order = dbm.getTasksOrderList()
        print(hash, tasks_order, task_id, datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S.%f"))
        tasks_order.remove(task_id)
        dbm.updateTasksOrderList(tasks_order)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        conn.rollback()
        raise e
    else:
        return {}, 204

I handle connections to the database as suggested in flask documentation.
def getConn():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
        db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

After running the service, I run a performance test in postman, which sends requests to addTask and deleteTask from 20 users. It proccesses few add and delete requests succesfully then fails.
I found out that it fails in deleteTask endpoint, when trying to remove a task_id from the array which doesn't exist. The weird thing that I see in logs that the insertion to the array (into the database) happened before calling deleteTask and I was able actually to see that in the logs. 
But when the connection to the db was closed (which happens after proccessing each request) and a new connection established (which happens when receiving a new request), the new connection cannot see the changes in the database. Why?!
logs:
?,PXYJ*pse added 237 02:51.805480
?,PXYJ*pse [54, 950, 86, 678, 417, 404, 237] 02:51.805480 # here we can see that on 02:51.805480 when I selected the array from the database, it included 237
t"qu5NI+bb todelete 237 02:51.903749
t"qu5NI+bb [54, 950, 86, 678, 417, 151] 237 02:51.905749 # here we can see that AFTER 02:51.805480 when I selected the array from the database, it doesn't include 237
t"qu5NI+bb ERROR OCCURED 237


Your code has a race condition bug – if two requests are updating the database concurrently, you'll lose some data. Having a database table with a single row with a single column is very much an anti-pattern anyway.

@AKX can you explain why is that? the database should handle locks to the database and deal with this issue.
Let's take an example a facebook post, two people can like or unlike that post concurrently and the same db will be updated (without taking db sharding/replication into account)

The database does handle locking if you just use it correctly, and you're not doing that with your antipattern design of a JSON string in a single row.

Your code has a race condition bug – if two requests are updating the database concurrently, you'll lose some data.
Consider this rudimentary concurrency diagram (time runs downwards), where the write of a is completely lost because Request 2 doesn't have any idea that it happened.
Assume "get list" means "SELECT + parse JSON", "add to list" is the Python append operation and "save list" is "dump JSON and UPDATE row".



Request 1
Request 2




get list -> []



add a to list -> [a]
get list -> []


save list [a]
add b to list -> [b]



save list [b]



If you wanted to avoid this with your current database design, you would need to SELECT order_list FROM tasks_order FOR UPDATE (so SELECT FOR UPDATE locks the rows), and update the row in the same transaction.
That said, having a database table with a single row with a single column is very much an anti-pattern anyway. It looks like you'd really want a CREATE TABLE tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY); – then adding an item is just an INSERT INTO tasks (id) VALUES (123);, deleting is DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = 123;, etc., and you don't need to work with JSON at all, and you wouldn't need locks either.
If the insertion order of the tasks is important, you could add a timestamp column that's automatically taken care of by the database:
sqlite> CREATE TABLE tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, insertion_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
sqlite> INSERT INTO tasks (id) VALUES (831);
sqlite> INSERT INTO tasks (id) VALUES (117);
sqlite> SELECT id FROM tasks ORDER by insertion_time;
831
117
sqlite> SELECT id FROM tasks ORDER by id;
117
831


Thanks for your reply, it's really helpful!
I need to elaborate more, the given example in the question is part from a large webapplication. I already have task_id as an integer and that's how I deal with tasks. I need the tasksOrder as a JSON to save the order of the tasks.

If the insertion order of the tasks is important, then add e.g. a timestamp column to tasks, and always ORDER BY insertion_time.

That's a good suggestion and I already considered it!
The problem is that the user in my application can change the order of the tasks as he wants, he can move a very old task above the newest one, and to handle this request I will just need to update the tasks_order list again

Well, then the name of the ordering column should probably be e.g. ordering, it should be a floating point or decimal value, and you would update it at will when your user reorders the tasks.

I should figure out how to do that

But can you explain to me how is that on the first request, when I selectTasksOrder after update I see that it includes 237, then a few miliseconds after that (as shown in the log), when I selectTasksOder from the second request, I can't see 237 in it, while inbetween these two operations nothing altered the list and the only thing that happened is that the connection is closed and reopened, can I conclude that while closing the connection, the engine still do operations on the database?

@user2401856 Well, now that I look at it, you're not even committing using the cursor in updateTasksOrderList, so how things work at all is a great big mystery. :)

I'm committing using the conn (you can see conn.commit() in the code)
Taking a second look at the whole logs I think your answer explains the scenario that is happening there. Thanks alot!!!

@user2401856 Erm, updateTasksOrderList() grabs its own connection and cursor, so I don't think so.

but I made sure in getConn() to save that connection in a global variable, so when I call updateTasksOrderList the connection has already been established and it works with it, then the caller function does the conn.commit()

Oh, I didn't notice that. Using a global variable is even worse, because now you have two concurrent requests using the same connection, and so you may end up having one request commit() a transaction another request is still busy with!

That won't happen because flask's g object is only global to the current request context and isn't shared between threads.
